# Creating a Finder alias using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, alias, finder

```
set folder_1 to text returned of (display dialog "Create Folders:" default answer "Type Here")
set folder_2 to "new_" & folder_1

set loc1 to ":path1"
set loc2 to ":path2"


tell application "Finder"
    set newfo1 to make new folder at loc1 with properties {name:folder_1}
    make new folder at newfo1 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo1 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo1 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo1 with properties {name:"new folder"}

    set newfo2 to make new folder at loc2 with properties {name:folder_2}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}
    make new folder at newfo2 with properties {name:"new folder"}

make alias at folder_1 to folder_2  

end tell
```

Can anybody shed light on creating an alias in the above code. I'm trying to create an alias of `{name:folder_2}` inside `{name:folder_1}` but using that variable I get a `Finder got an error: AppleEvent handler failed`. Could anyone help out?

Very many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you need to do is to change your `make alias` statement to use the newly created folder *objects*:

```
make alias at newfo1 to newfo2
```

Note that your code doesn't deal with the cases where any of the folders you create already exist (in which case you'd get `error "The operation can’t be completed because there is already an item with that name." number -48`).